# Handle "Cannot access a closed resource set"

Tags: asp.net, localization, resx

I have a website with several languages in a database. From the database I use ResXResourceWriter to create my .resx files. This is working really good but sometimes I get this exception:

```
MESSAGE: Cannot access a closed resource set.
SOURCE: mscorlib
FORM: 
QUERYSTRING: 
TARGETSITE: System.Object GetObject(System.String, Boolean, Boolean)
STACKTRACE:    at System.Resources.RuntimeResourceSet.GetObject(String key, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean isString)
  at System.Resources.RuntimeResourceSet.GetString(String key, Boolean ignoreCase)
  at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture)
  at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateStaticOrInstanceMethod(Expression instance, MethodInfo method)
  at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
  at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.GetMethodCall(Object instance, MethodInfo methodInfo, Object[] parameters)
  at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.ExecuteMethodCall(Object instance, MethodInfo methodInfo, Object[] parameters)
  at Business.DatabaseModelDataContext.Web_GetMostPlayedEvents(String cultureCode)
  at Presentation.Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
  at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
  at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

I don't know why this is happening or how to solve it. Does anyone know anything about this?

Thanks,
Philip

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you closed your DataSource prematurely or didn't close it at all when your program routine is about to end?

Comment: No it is nothing wong with the DataSource, for that I am sure. It must be something with how the .resx are created or that I miss something. But they are always created succesfully but I am getting the exception when they are used in my website.